# Dim vs Private/Public

Tags: vb.net, scope

At the head of a module, I wish to declare some global variables for use in various subs/functions.

What is the difference between

`Dim x as string` and `Private x as string` / `Public x as string`, and when would I use one over the other?

Comment: Don't forget `Friend x as String`

Comment: This [post][1] has a better answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401372/difference-between-dim-and-private-inside-a-vb-net-form

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Private and public control the scope of the variable or object you're declaring.

`Private` will only allow members of the relative module/class/whatever to access the instance

`public` will allow anything in the same scope as the module/class/whatever to access it.

`Dim` defaults to either public or private, depending on what you're working in.  A class for example, will default to private.  I suggest reading up on encapsulation and OOP to get a better feel for this.

Comment: Yes, but what's the difference if you use Dim or not?

Comment: Please read the answer again.  I said dim defaults the scope to public or private depending on whether you're in a structure or class, respectively.

Comment: Could do with more detail of what dim defaults to

Comment: It's stated pretty plainly.

Answer (score 2):

They are different, but related, things.

[Dim Statement (Visual Basic) [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx) tells us:

> [Dim] Declares and allocates storage space for one or more variables.

and

> The Dim keyword is optional and usually omitted if you specify any of the following modifiers: Public, Protected, Friend, Protected Friend, Private, Shared, Shadows, Static, ReadOnly, or WithEvents.

[Access Levels in Visual Basic [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx) tells us:

> Private (and Public, Protected, Friend, Protected Friend) are Access Modifiers  which specify 'what code has permission to read it or write to it.'

and

> At the module level, the Dim statement without any access level keywords is equivalent to a Private declaration. However, you might want to use the Private keyword to make your code easier to read and interpret.

so `Private x As String` is the equivalent of `Dim Private x As String` (although if you type this Visual Studio will remove the Dim)

and `Dim x As String` is equivalent to `Private x As String` except in Structures (where it is equivalent to `Public x As String`) and interfaces where declaring variables is not allowed - see [Declaration Contexts and Default Access Levels (Visual Basic) [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235296.aspx)