# Public Sub vs Sub?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2013, private

Ok so I would like to know the difference with Public Subs and just normal Subs. Can normal subs be accessed by another program.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, the title does not say it all here (that's why we have the small area in which to type it, and the large area to allow you to provide information and actually ask a question). In addition, your title says "use a Public Sub", while your question asks about using a "Private Sub". And "I want it still private but another form to be able to access it" doesn't make sense - if it's **private**, another form can't use it, and if another form **can** use it, it's **not private**. If your question isn't worth yout effort to ask, it's not worth ours to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dim vs Private/Public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853298/dim-vs-private-public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not whether they can be accessed by other programs, but whether they can be accessed from other types (Classes/Modules) within the same program.