# VBA globals declarations

Tags: excel, vba

This is a really naive question, I am guessing. I have some global variables

```
Dim foo, bar as Double
```

Which are then set to something:

```
Sub setter()
   foo = 3.14
   bar = 2.718
End Sub
```

I want the variables to be initialized on startup, which, I gather can be done with

```
 Private Sub Auto_open()
     Call setter
 End Sub
```

The question is: will this pick up the declarations, or is there some other magic I need to do?

Comment: That should be fine.  FYI you only declare `bar` as double: foo is Variant.  You need to declare the type for each variable

Comment: Never use `Dim` on global variables. Define their scope with `Private` or `Public`.

Comment: @HackSlash I am happy to comply, but just for my own enlightenment, why? Does Dim default to Public?

Comment: Depends on where it is used. It's best to be clear about your intention. `Dim` offers no indicator of scope. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853298/dim-vs-private-public

Comment: @HackSlash that link is for VB.NET. In VBA the `Dim` keyword declares a local variable in a procedure scope, or a `Private` variable in module scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use Properties instead. That is what they are for. This gives you a globally readable property that can only be set locally by the initializer.

EXAMPLE:

```
Option Explicit

Private localFoo As Double

Private Property Let foo(fooval As Double)
    localFoo = fooval
End Property

Public Property Get foo() As Double
    foo = localFoo
End Property

Private Sub Auto_open()
    initFoo
End Sub

Private Sub initFoo()
    foo 3.14
End Sub
```

SOURCE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-set-statement

Comment: Perhaps whoever downvoted this can explain why they did. As for me, my concern with this method is its verbosity. I have fifty parameters for a model I am working on, and this method would generate about five hundred lines of code, which some would view as error-prone. Any words of wisdom?

Comment: My advice is to reconsider why you need 50 global variables. That sounds like bad design. What are you making that requires such a large number of external properties? Do they need to be visible outside this module or can they be private to the module?

Comment: Well, these are excellent questions. To answer them, this is a financial model, so there are things like borrowing interest rate, inflation rate, various fixed costs, and so on - these can change depending on circumstances, so should be variable. , or variable-like. Now, as for visibility, there are the default values, which I initialize in "ThisWorkbook", but also the user can set them by filling in cells (which live in an "Inputs" sheet), and if an input cell is changed, the has to be a recalc. This seems to indicate that I need them public, but (obviously) I am no VBA expert.

Comment: Gleesh. I would store all user facing data on the spreadsheet. Never hard code numbers in to your code unless they are part of a formula that never changes, like the constant for Pi. Each formula needs it's own function with inputs passed in to the function and the answer as the return value. No global variables are needed when passing values between functions. You can chain the functions together, passing the answers around until your calculation is complete, at which point you return the value to the spreadsheet. Inputs and outputs are then user facing on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

`Dim` can't be used to declare globals. Use `Dim` for declaring local variables inside a procedure scope.

When used at module level, `Dim` is equivalent to `Private`, and you should use `Private` instead, for consistency (`Private` antagonizes `Public` much more clearly than `Dim` does).

> ```
> Dim foo, bar as Double
> ```

Note that this makes `bar` a `Double`, and leaves `foo` an implicit `Variant`. If both are intended to be `Double`, then the declaration should look like this:

```
Dim foo As Double, bar As Double
```

I would recommend declaring one single variable per statement.

```
Dim foo As Double
Dim bar As Double
```

Much easier to maintain that way.

As for your question, assuming everything is in the same module, you're fine - and the variables don't need to be global (`Public` - there's a `Global` keyword too, but you can only use it in a standard module, and it's functionally identical to `Public`, so don't use `Global`, it's obsolete), since no other module needs to access them.

Note that it's very, very, very rare that you **need** global variables. Most of the time, you'll be passing parameters between procedures instead.

Comment: My general preference is for functional languages, so I feel your pain re globals, however, the truth is that often one does need state, and a lot of it. The "clean"(er) way is to use closures/classes, but that is not functionally different from Private variables (since, if I understand correctly, "ThisWorkbook" IS in fact a class). Giving every procedure fifty arguments is generally a poor idea, and passing a dictionary of key value pairs is, functionally identical to the Private mechanism, and produces ugly code.

Comment: @IgorRivin `ThisWorkbook` is indeed a class, and I never said you don't need any state. In fact nothing prevents you from adding a class module to your project and making it expose 50 public fields (that compiles down to 50 read/write properties on the class' default interface). Careful not to confuse *state* for *data*: VBA code hosted in an Excel document has the opportunity to leverage worksheets to persist data; state in code is fine, data in code isn't. I'd suggest posting your finished, working code to [codereview.se] if you want feedback on any/all aspects of it. Cheers!