# VB.NET, keywords as variable names

Tags: vb.net, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

I have to deserialize some json data string into structure.
Problem is that data names conflicts vith VB keywords what is in C# not a case.

This is json string:

```
{"id":2526068,"date":"2019-07-21T19:15:17.4468196+02:00","error":""}
```

Problematic names are obviously "date" and "error". Somewhere I found that such variables should be surrended with []. But this don't work for me.
Here is my code:

```
Structure reqjson
    Dim id As String
    Dim [date] As String
    Dim [error] As String
End Structure

Dim idnum As Long = 0
Dim sldate As String = ""
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonstr) Then
        Dim r As reqjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of reqjson)(jsonstr)
        idnum = CLng(r.id)
        sladate = r.date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy. hh:mm:ss.fff")
End If
```

Problem is that deserializer can't deserialize data if they don't have a same name what VB don't allow. In C# this declaration is legal:

```
struct reqjson{
string id;
string date;
string error;
};
```

But not in VB.NET. What to do here?

Comment: `<JsonProperty("date")> Dim MyNamedDate As String`

Comment: Deserializes to `MyNamedDate`, serializes to `date`. Possibly, use a class instead of a structure. You should use a class (I changed my mind :)

Comment: WOW, that works. Thank you very much Jimi!

Comment: See [djv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57172172/7444103)'s answer. There are things you need to take care of (Btw, use a class, possibly. With public members).

Comment: Jimi, I want to keep minimalistic approach on this case so structure is here more convinient for me.

Comment: A class is as minimalistic as a structure (same number of lines) but it's more flexible.

Comment: Some interesting reading on this thema: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/interview-question/advantage-of-struct-over-classes

Comment: Yes, well, that little article fails to mention what happens when you need to pass around those objects and that the garbage collector for managed types works in the background and collects what needs to be collected when the application is all/partially idle. With elements of these sizes, there's no difference in memory usage. It may affect code usage, though.

Comment: If a struct represents a de jure value (such that multiple instances with the same contents are interchangeable i.e. it's immutable) then it's fine and the only consideration is efficiency.  Otherwise, it becomes hard to reason about and can make for some nasty bugs when the runtime makes a copy when you don't expect it.  So you should be *very* skeptical of a struct which has anything that is *not* `ReadOnly` in its public interface.

Comment: I think that article is poor.  It oversimplifies the performance picture (the supposed gains can disappear when the CRL starts copying them as can happen) and completely fails to discuss the importance of immutability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your deserialization. Your code works for me!

But perhaps you should address a couple potential issues. Don't use `Dim` for class level fields. Use `Public` or `Private`

```vb
Structure reqjson
    Public id As String
    Public [date] As String
    Public [error] As String
End Structure
```

And I'm not changing anything here, other than adding the json string myself

```vb
Public Shared Sub foo()
    Dim jsonstr = "{""id"":2526068,""Date"":""2019-07-21T19:15:17.4468196+02:00"",""error"":""""}"
    Dim idnum As Long = 0
    Dim sldate As String = ""
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonstr) Then
        Dim r As reqjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of reqjson)(jsonstr)
        idnum = CLng(r.id)
```

However, you are doing `String.ToString()`. Try this instead

```
        sldate = Date.Parse(r.date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy. hh:mm:ss.fff")
    End If
End Sub
```

Or better yet, use an actual date in the struct

```vb
Structure reqjson
    Public id As String
    Public [date] As Date
    Public [error] As String
End Structure
```

which makes your original code work

```
sldate = r.date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy. hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

Comment: That actually works for me too now. It seem's that I has some error with input data. Also work's with dim! I'm sorry for a type mismatch. It appears when I prepare this example otherwise I have option strict turned on. Thank you.

Comment: You can deserialize to `DateTimeOffset`. Much better than Date. It will preserve the offset of the original Date.

Comment: Jimi, never hear for that. But also works with Dim [date] As DateTimeOffset.

Comment: With a standard *interational* date format as this: `2019-07-21T19:15:17.4468196+02:00`, If you don't use `DateTimeOffset`, the original offset is lost. When you seriaiize again, you'll add the local offset, which may (will) be different from the original. Test it changing the current offset `+2.00` with an offset different from your local offset. You'll see.

Comment: That is useful to know. Thank you again!

Comment: @WineToo maybe you just needed to double-up on the double quotes to escape them. Yes Dim works but [Dim alone is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401372/difference-between-dim-and-private). You should always provide the access modifier, and when it is there, Dim is not required. AND, in VB Structures, all members are public by default so not providing Public or Private will result in Dim being public. This is the opposite of C#. So you should be explicit and put an access modifier to avoid confusion :)

Comment: djv, this string is already in PostgreSQL database where is stored escaped. I personally rather use single than double quotes not just because it is simpler for usage but because I can't do so much double quotes in the string without lost myself in that. Especially problematic for me are quotes when I have to construct a string with switches in Process code :(